# Is it possible to create a global alias for a table in psql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, alias

We have a table called Table1, and we want to create an alias for it, e.g. Table2, so that in any query it is understood as Table1. Is it possible in psql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a view:

```
create view table2 as
     select * from table1;
```

Comment: but that's only for the select, I would like update Table or insert into Table2 to work just the same

Comment: @giladrv: that view will be fully updateable.

Comment: Short answer **No** you cannot create a global ALIAS for a table. An alias is specific to the query in which it occurs. In fact the same alias can be used to refer to different "objects" in the same query. Also the same alias may be used in different query to refer to completely different objects.  The view suggestion does not create an alias but a different database object in the data dictionary - although the net effect is the same. In Oracle (perhaps other RDBMS as well) you could create a synonym for this, Postgres however does not support synonyms.